# What is tmp.0.sDQWBe?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, storage, macos

I have a file called `tmp.0.sDQWBe` located on my MacBook/Macintosh HD `/private/var/folders/k1/(a ton of random text)/T/tmp.0.sDQWBe`. The file is 13.2GB and I have **no idea** what it is.

I want to delete it so it can free up space on my computer. What is it, and can I delete it?

Comment: If you reboot the Mac does the file still exist and at that size?

Comment: Yes it does, it is weird.

Comment: The fact that the file's name starts with "tmp." is a good indication that it's meant to be temporary and given its location, I'd say it was safe to delete.  That said, it goes without saying... always make sure you have a backup just in case.  In Terminal, I'd move it to a different name, adding say ".bak" to it, then reboot and see if the file is recreated.  If it's not and everything appears to be okay, then delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple reboot may purge some of this. /var is generally for variable files (caches, logs, etc). You can check to see which process is using the file before deleting, if it is indeed open. [There are a number of ways to do this via the terminal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x)

After a little research I found this gem of an article, [What is "/var/folders"?](http://www.magnusviri.com/OS_X_Admin/what-is-var-folders.html).